# The less you have

Tags: riddle

Can you tell me?

The less you have, the more likely is it for you to lose it. What am I thinking about?

Comment: I like this one, but as you can see from the answers, it is a broad question. Next time, try to be a little more specific.

Comment: @JanMer - welcome to Puzzling.SE! Note that your riddle is pulling in various seemingly correct answers. Riddles of this nature are often flagged/closed as being too broad, since the expectation is that a riddle come down to exactly one correct answer (there may be other answers that come close, but not all the way). [This meta QA](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4573/what-exactly-is-too-broad) would help you get an idea of what is too broad, and what is a well-specified question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you

> patience?

Because

> If you are not that patient, you will lose patience easily

Answer (score 9):

Let's give it a noteworthy shot.

> Chess/checkers pieces.

The less you have, the more likely is it for you to lose it.

> With fewer pieces, it might be harder to prevent the opponent from taking them. 
>  If you don't believe me, try defending your 5 remaining pawns from a bloodthirsty queen.

Comment: Ah this one's simply out of the park. =D

Answer (score 9):

> **Balance**
>  Since, the less balance you have, more likely to lose it.

Answer (score 4):

It could be

> Poker Chips because you will lose them to the beginning pot and you cannot take risky bets.

Comment: I liked your previous answer better. The rot13:cbxre puvcf

Answer (score 4):

This could be a lot of things, like:

> Hope, Focus, Confidence, Trust - the less you have of each of these, the easier it is to lose them.

In addition to all the other good answers already posted.